# Public Key / Private Key Generation in a bash script (osx / ubuntu)

Tags: private-key, script, public-key

I am creating a bash script (that I will happily share on github when done) that takes random public and private keys for bitcoin and then bottles them up in an AES encrypted container and then SSSS the key to unlock. (Aka, a really secure paper wallet to distribute but itself is worthless. ) For right now, the part that I have thus far "outsourced" was the public / private key generation using bitaddress.org to create the bulk addresses. I would like to pull that part into the bash script.

I have reviewed, 
https://github.com/RobKohr/PHP-Bitcoin-Address-Creator/blob/master/lib/botg.sh
and found that 50% of the time the private key in fact does not "unlock" the public key. Further it only runs in Ubuntu not OSX. Further, my goal is to replicate the bulk function such that 50 or 1000 address could be created.

Does anyone have any scripts or suggested links / locations / examples to accomplish the creation of the key pairs?

Appreciated.

Comment: Does SSSS refer to the Shamir Secret Sharing Scheme?

Answer (score 1):

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Vanitygen is a software which will generate BTC address keypairs at the command-line. Its main purpose is actually to generate "vanity" addresses which contain pretty custom strings, but if you run it as follows then you will get a continuous output of many random public-private pairs: ./vanitygen -k 1 (remove the -k to generate only a single pair rather than continuously generate). I have used these addresses in my testing (sending small amounts), and have always found the private-key to be successfully importable and usable in a wallet. I have personally run vanitygen on ubuntu precise and mac os x mt lion.